# Pig one row to multiple row

Tags: apache-pig

Can you please provide Pig script for below query?

here's input format.
**Input**

```
ID, Label  
122,a|b
215,q|b|c
214,Z|b|c
218,w|b|c
211,r|b|c
219,u|b
```

**Expected output**

```
122,a    
122,b
215,q
215,b
215,c
214,Z
214,b
214,c
218,w
218,b
218,c

...........
```

Thanks,

Abhi

Comment: You may want to explain your result and what you've already been trying. For example, you're not saying _why_ 211, 218, 219 should be excluded, just that they should be.

Comment: I have corrected it. Thanks for highlighting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TOKENIZE the Label, it will give a bag and than FLATTEN it, which will give you as many rows as are tuples in the bag. Sample code

```
inpt = LOAD '....' USING PigStorage(',') AS (ID: chararray, Label : chararray);
result = FOREACH inpt GENERATE ID, FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(Lable, '|'));

DUMP result;
```